# Как можно текст placeholder-а перенести на новую линию?

Tags: html, css

[image: different amount]

```html
 <input type="text" placeholder="different amount"/>
```

Comment: Он должен сместиться? Если так, то нужно делать через input+label, и позиционировать label, placeholder скрывается при вводе

Comment: @RuslanSemenov на картинке показано как должно выглядеть

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea

Comment: @entithat я это уже увидел,там написано для textarea, a мне нужно для инпута

Comment: @JoraSahakyan, ну в первом ответе написал, что это невозможно..

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

```css
.test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative
}

.test input {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center; 
}

.test label {
  z-index: -1;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;
  opacity: 1;
}

.test input:focus~label,
.test input:valid~label {
  transform: translate(-50%, -150%);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <input required>
  <label>текст<br>в две строки<br>да хоть в три</label>
</div>
```